# How to move down UITableView after presenting a UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` with just a `UITableView` in it. It has search functionalities using `UISearchController`. Unfortunately everytime I present the search controller, some part of the tableview is hidden behind the search controller. What I want to do is to animate the table view down slightly when the search controller is being presented, so I did it like this:

```
class SearchTableVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // The top constraint IB Outlet from the storyboard

private var searchController: UISearchController!

//....

   @objc private func presentSearchController() { // Called from a Navigation Bar Item
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        
        tableViewTopConstraint.constant = searchController.searchBar.frame.height // This line is to move the table view down slightly
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

//....

}

extension SearchTableVC: UISearchControllerDelegate {

   //....

   func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.tableViewTopConstraint.constant = 0 // This line is to move the table view back to the top (right under the navigation bar)
        }
    }

   //....

}
```

It works fine but the moving animation is not smooth and I think what I did is not the right way to do it, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: so why don't you animate moving table view down like you did when you set the constraint to 0?

Comment: @setonugroho i did do that as well, but the animation doesn't work properly. Actually it doesn't animate at all

Comment: 0.2 sec is pretty fast. Are you sure it doesn't animate at all?